# 18.04 keyboard stop working for one user account after login; another works ok

Tags: keyboard, login, users

I've got a high school computer lab with 32 Dells running 18.04.

A problem has developed on two computers now, where after logging in with the student account, the keyboard stops working. Even caps lock / num lock are non responsive. We saw on one computer there was really long latency, as in 10+ seconds, between keypress and execution.

If I log out w the mouse options and login with the admin account, keyboard is fine. So the problem seems to be bound to the particular user account.

Any suggestions ?

Thanks ~~~

Comment: Very long wild shot. `gconftool-2 --get /desktop/gnome/accessibility/keyboard/slowkeys_enable`

Comment: Yep I adjusted my search and found a bunch of links regarding Slow Keys. I'm headed into the lab today and that sounds like it could be the fix.